# How to create Truecrypt volume using zuluCrypt?

Tags: 14.04, encryption, arm, truecrypt

I liked to use the GUI zuluCrypt to CREATE truecrypt volumes..I followed the instructions here https://code.google.com/p/zulucrypt/ but when I want to create a encrypted container (create => encrypted container in a file) I can only choose between LUKS and plain. I installed cryptsetup, tcplay and in the end zuluCrypt. Any suggestions?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on Samsung ARM XE303C12 installed via this script
http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.ch/2013/05/chrubuntu-one-script-to-rule-them-all_31.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zuluCrypt creates TrueCrypt volumes when it finds atleast version 2.0 of tcplay[1]

Make sure you have tcplay together with its development files installed and then rebuild zuluCrypt and it should pick up tcplay and it will then start
creating TrueCrypt volumes.

[1] https://github.com/bwalex/tc-play